# sum of first $p$ even numbers is $1+\frac 1p$ times the sum of first $p$ odd numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that the sum of first $p$ even numbers is $1+\frac 1p$ times the sum of first $p$ odd numbers.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: I assume that you know a formula for the sum of the first $n$ positive integers. Let $a_p$ be the sum of the first $p$ even positive integers and $b_p$ the sum of the first $p$ odd positive integers. Note that $a_p+b_p$ is the sum of the first $2p$ positive integers, which you can find. Thus, if you can find at least one of $a_p$ and $b_p$, you can find the other. And you can find $a_p$ quite easily in terms of the sum of the first $p$ positive integers.

Alternatively, you can get $a_p$ and $b_p$ by using the general formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression.